# Nanotime formatting with underscore separator for fractional seconds

Tags: r, nanotime

Working with nanoseconds from epoch is a breeze with `nanotime`, e.g.:

```
> x  <- 1639142792837258898
> xn <- nanotime::nanotime(x)
> xn
[1] 2021-12-10T22:26:32.837259008+09:00
> format(xn, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E9S")
[1] "2021-12-10T22:26:32.837259008"
```

`nanotime` also allows to use an underscore as separator for fractions of seconds **when parsing**, like so:

```
> y <- nanotime::as.nanotime("2021-12-10T22:26:32.837_259_008+09:00")
> y
[1] 2021-12-10T22:26:32.837259008+09:00
```

How can I achieve the same style **when formatting**?